# Spring boot with spring session and security. RMI fails with 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I'm using Spring boot with spring security and Spring Session with redis for authentication and authorization. There are two separate projects running and I want to connect them with `RMI tunneled over HTTP`.
Even though I've used `setRemoteInvocationFactory` in `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` Since the 2nd service throws 401. I'm getting Internal server error. What's the workaround?

I'm passing session id in the header as `x-auth-token`. Should I pass the same through service invoker?

Here is the code

#### Exporter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ServiceExporter {
    @Bean(name = "/rmi")
    HttpInvokerServiceExporter accountService(@Autowired rmiimpl rmi) {
        HttpInvokerServiceExporter exporter = new HttpInvokerServiceExporter();
        exporter.setServiceInterface(rmiinterface.class);
        exporter.setService(rmi);
        return exporter;
    }
}
```

#### Invoker:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class test {

    @Bean
    public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker() {
        HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
        String serviceURL = "http://localhost:8081/rmi";
        invoker.setServiceUrl(serviceURL);
        invoker.setServiceInterface(rmiinterface.class);
        invoker.setRemoteInvocationFactory(remoteinvocation());
        return invoker;
    }

    @Bean
    RemoteInvocationFactory remoteinvocation() {
        return new ContextPropagatingRemoteInvocationFactory();
    }

}
```

#### SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SessionSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("adminPass").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers("/auth/*").fullyAuthenticated() //
                .and().requestCache() //
                .requestCache(new NullRequestCache()) //
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

#### Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Did not receive successful HTTP response: status code = 401, status message = [null]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.validateResponse(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:188) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:92) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:202) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:184) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:150) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.rmitext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.controller.AuthController.test(AuthController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:171) ~[spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Not sure what's missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally Figured out.

AS we all know that Spring Security reads Session Id from cookie by default. In this case, since I've used `@Bean public HttpSessionStrategy` it reads from header `x-auth-token`.

Whenever `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` tries to connect the authentication context is propagated but since it's an HTTP call the default spring session filter tries reading the session ID and validate the same. Since here session Id is not transmitted it throws 401.

In order to fix it. I need to set the `header` in HTTP invoker. The same applies if  `cookie` is used. Since `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` uses `SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor`. I created a new class by extending it and added the header by overriding `prepareConnection`. I used `setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor` in invoker to set the executor to call the new class.

Here is the code.

#### Invoker:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class test {

    @Bean
    public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker() {
        HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
        String serviceURL = "http://localhost:8081/rmi";
        invoker.setServiceUrl(serviceURL);
        invoker.setServiceInterface(rmiinterface.class);
        invoker.setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(httpInvokerRequestExecutor()); //call to the bean
        return invoker;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor httpInvokerRequestExecutor() {
        return new CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();
    }
}

class CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor extends SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor {

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, int contentLength) throws IOException {
        // adding header.
        connection.addRequestProperty("x-auth-token", session.getId());
        super.prepareConnection(connection, contentLength);
    }
}
```

Now it started working.